# How do I use easy_install and buildout when pypi is down?

Tags: python, plone, easy-install, buildout

I am using [buildout](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.buildout) to automatically download and setup the many dependencies of my Plone installation. buildout more or less uses easy_install to download and install a bunch of Python eggs. This usually works, but it doesn't work if any of the dependencies cannot be downloaded or if I want buildout to find an internal package not appropriate for pypi. How can I set up my own local version of pypi to automatically mirror the packages I need? Will it still depend on third-party servers for packages that use pypi for their metadata but not their code?

Comment: Most of the answers below are not mutually exclusive: use at least one, but consider more: a download cache locally in your buildout, a private index with just packages you need (from your download-cache), and possibly a PyPI mirror per MrTopf's answer below.  I usually do at least 2 of these three when I expect to work offline for more than a few hours.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here are [instructions on how to setup your own PyPi mirror](http://www.zopyx.de/blog/creating-a-local-pypi-mirror). The homepage of this project is [here](http://www.openplans.org/projects/pypi-mirroring/project-home). There also seems to be a growing number of mirrors out there.

For instructions on how to setup your own package index, check out [this blog post](http://plope.com/Members/chrism/distribution_links_considered_harmful) where one solution is explained at the end. Then you can also host your own internal packages in there. The advantage is also that the versions are fixed that way. (For a way to pin the versions directly in buildout, check out [this post](http://maurits.vanrees.org/weblog/archive/2008/01/easily-creating-repeatable-buildouts)).

If there is only metadata on PyPI and the archive is stored somewhere else you might of course copy that over to your index as well. If you just use a PyPI mirror I assume that you still need access to these servers.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use a mirror. Put this in the "[global]" section of "~/.pip/pip.conf":

```
index-url = http://d.pypi.python.org/simple/
```

This is a recent feature as announced [here](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/catalog-sig/2010-July/003132.html).

Answer (score 5):

This page shows how to use the alternate mirror mentioned in @moraes post, but for easy_install, buildout and virtualenv as well as pip:

http://jacobian.org/writing/when-pypi-goes-down/

Answer (score 4):

In case of zc.buildout: use its local download caching features. There are mostly three things to cache:

- external extends, i.e. http://dist.plone.org/release/4.1.2/versions.cfg
- eggs from some distserver, i.e. pypi
- downloads from zc.recipe.cmmi or similar recipes using the download infrastructure provided by zc.buildout

For all three we need to tweak the global configuration and set a cache folder for the extends and one for eggs and other downloads.

In your home folder create a `.buildout` folder.

In this folder create the folders `extends-cache` and `downloads`

In `.buildout` create a file default.cfg with:

```
[buildout]  
extends-cache = /home/USERNAME/.buildout/extends-cache 
download-cache = /home/USERNAME/.buildout/downloads
```

so you have:

```
.buildout/
├── default.cfg
├── downloads
└── extends-cache
```

Thats it. Make sure to not override these two variables from default.cfg in your specific buildout. After first successful run of buildout subsequent runs are running in offline mode `./bin/buildout -o`.

As a side effect buildout is much faster if used in offline mode, i.e. when no new downloads are expected but some configuration changed

Beside this it makes sense to run your own pypi-mirror. As another source of information you might be interested in the article I wrote some time ago about this topic: http://bluedynamics.com/articles/jens/setup-z3c.pypimirror

Comment: This got me started, but the -o option appears to be broken (see https://github.com/buildout/buildout/issues/41). I used the config option `install-from-cache = true` while specifying the `download-cache` as above, and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Configure `index` in `buildout.cfg`, e.g.

```
[buildout]
index = http://a.pypi.python.org/
find-links =
```

More mirrors on : http://www.pypi-mirrors.org/

Answer (score 0):

PyPI has had mirroring since mid 2010 http://pypi.python.org/mirrors

Answer (score 0):

For the packages, that you need to install in your `virtualenv` usually through a `requirements.txt` (or may be individually), you have to override your `pip.conf` file, usually located at `~/.pip/pip.conf`

In your `pip.conf` file:

```
[global]
index-url=https://pypi.python.org/simple/

[install]
trusted-host=pypi.python.org
```

Here you can provide the url of your own custom version of pypi if needed.

If you wish to also use another pypi server while creating `virtualenv` through `easy_install` you need to override `pydistutils.cfg` file usually located at `~/pydistutils.cfg`

In `pydistutils.cfg` file:

```
[easy_install]
index-url=https://pypi.python.org/simple/
```

This would ensure to create your `venv` with the url of pypi mentioned in `pydistutils.cfg`. Here, we're telling `easy_install` to use https://pypi.python.org/simple/ for creating `venvs`.